# Why can't I add constant of other class into a switch statement in java?

Tags: java, switch-statement, constants

Why can't I add constant of other class into a switch statement in java?

example: I have a class

```
public class Game {


    static class GameMode {
        public static final GameMode SURVIVAL = new GameMode();
        public static final GameMode ADVENTURE = new GameMode();
        public static final GameMode GOD = new GameMode();
    }

    GameMode CurrentMode = GameMode.GOD;

}
```

but when I define a switch statement, It give me an error:

```
    void OnGame(){
        switch (CurrentMode){
            case GameMode.GOD: // case expressions must be constant expressionsJava(536871065)
                System.out.println("Player On God Mode");
                break;
            case GameMode.SURVIVAL: // case expressions must be constant expressionsJava(536871065)
                System.out.println("Player On Survival Mode");
                break;
            case GameMode.ADVENTURE: // case expressions must be constant expressionsJava(536871065)
                System.out.println("Player On Adventure Mode");
                break;


        }
    }
```

That makes me confused. SURVIVAL, ADVENTURE and GOD mode are all constant, I add "final" in front of it, why can't I use it in switch statement?

Here are some image:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/index.html) (JLS):

> A case label has one or more case constants. Every case constant must be either a constant expression (§15.29) or the name of an enum constant (§8.9.1), or a compile-time error occurs.

Your case is obviously not an `enum constant`, so I guess you are trying to use a [`constant expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29) but your `GameMode` class does not qualify as a `constant expression`.

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only [the following](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)...

Comment: So that means I can only use Primitive type / String, and I cannot use other object in switch statement?

Comment: Yes, with the exception of enum. Enum can be used and since they can be customized to an extent, it's a perfect solution